# Expectation of Stopping Time w.r.t a Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

How do you take the expectation of a stopping time with respect to a Brownian motion?  The specific question is:

$$
\tau = \inf\{ t \ge 0: B(t) \in \{-a, b\}\}
$$

I understand the optional stopping theorem tells us that $E[M_\tau ] = E[M_0]$ but how do I use that to find the expectation?

Comment: Do you mean $B$ instead of $M$?

Comment: Using M as any martingale such that the optional stopping theorem states: Let $\tau$ be a stopping time and $M_n$ be a martingale. If there is $K\in \mathbb(N)$ such that $\tau \le K$ almost surely then $E(M_{\tau})=E(M_0)$.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to find an expression for?

Comment: I'm looking how to solve $E(\tau )$ in general.  The stopping time defined in the original question is a practice question for my final.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We want to use the optional stopping theorem on the two martingales $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and $(B_t^2-t)_{t\geq 0}$. Note that $\tau<\infty$ a.s. so $B_\tau \in \{-a,b\}$ a.s. and hence by the optional stopping theorem, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
0&=E[B_0]=E[B_\tau]=-aP(B_\tau=-a)+bP(B_\tau=b)\\
&=-a(1-P(B_\tau=b))+bP(B_\tau=b)
\end{align*}
$$
which implies that
$$
P(B_\tau=b)=\frac{a}{a+b},\quad P(B_\tau=-a)=\frac{b}{a+b}.
$$
Using the optional stopping theorem on $(B_t^2-t)_{t\geq 0}$ we get that
$$
0=E[B_0^2-0]=E[B_\tau^2-\tau]
$$
and hence
$$
E[\tau]=E[B_\tau^2]=a^2P(B_\tau=-a)+b^2P(B_\tau=b)=ab.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The first part this question comes from asks to prove that $(B^2_t - t)$ is a martingale. I never made the connection nor what the usefulness of the stopping theorem was. Two questions. How do you get $P(B_{\tau}=-a) = 1 - P(B_{\tau})$?  How do you get $P(B_{\tau}=b)$?

Comment: Because $B_\tau\in \{-a,b\}$ a.s. means exactly that $P(B_\tau=-a)+P(B_\tau=b)=1$ and therefore $P(B_\tau=-a)=1-P(B_\tau=b)$. I got $P(B_\tau=b)$ by solving for it in the equation$$0=-a(1-P(B_\tau=b))+bP(B_\tau=b).$$

Comment: You just blew my mind.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Why does $E[\tau]=E[B_{\tau}^2]$?

Comment: @Rasputin That follows from the line just above.

Comment: How did you pass t to infinity for $B^2_{t \land \tau}-(t\land \tau)$ in the last but the second equation? Did you use DCT? Thank you so much!

Comment: @StefanHansen How is the last line equal to ab? Can you add some more details to that relation?

Comment: @benso8 for obtain $ab$ just replace the values of the probabilities and make some steps of algebra.