# Find stopping times $S$ and $T$ of Brownian motion $B$ such that $S\le T$, $E[S]$ finite, and $E[B(S)^2]>E[B(T)^2]$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

This is exercise 2.12 of Peter Morters and Yuval Peres' book Brownian Motion:

> Find two stopping times $S\le T$ with $E[S]<\infty$ such that $E[B(S)^2]>E[B(T)^2]$.

I considered about deterministic stopping times, but it does not work. And by Wald's Lemma, it seems we need to find a stopping time $T$ with $E[T]=\infty$. While Wald's second lemma says $E[B(S)^2]=E[S]$. May I get some hint about it?

Comment: $$S=\inf\{t\mid B_t\in\{-1,2\}\}\quad T=\inf\{t\mid B_t=-1\}$$

Comment: I checked these stopping times satisfying all requirements except $E[S]<\infty.$ I know $E[T]=\infty$ and $P(S<\infty)=1$. But I don't know if $E[S]<\infty.$ I try to use $E[S]=\int_0^\infty P(S>x)dx$ and use $P(S>x)\le P(B_s\in (-1,2))$ but it seems does't work. I wonder if there is a way to show $E[S]<\infty$.

Comment: I find this question solving it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261889/expectation-of-stopping-time-w-r-t-a-brownian-motion

Comment: $E(S)=(0-(-1))(2-0)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. In general if $S=\inf\{t:|B(t)|=a\}$ and $B(0)=x$, then $\mathbb{E}[S]=a^2-x^2$. You can find the expectation of your $S$ by shifting but maybe just make $S=\inf\{t:B(t)\in\{-1,1\}$ instead.

Comment: If $S=\inf\{t\mid B_t\in\{-1,1\}\}$, as you suggest, what is $T$?

Comment: Let $T=\inf\{t:B_t=-1\}$ as you originally stated.

Comment: Then $E(B_S^2)=1=E(B_T^2)$, not $E(B_S^2)>E(B_T^2)$, thus you have no example.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. How about $T=\inf\{t>S:B_t=0\}$?

Comment: This one works.