# If $\tau=\inf \{t \ge 0: B(t)= -a \text{ or } b\}$ is a stopping time of Brownian motion $B_t$, why does $E(\tau)=E(B_{\tau}^2)$?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times, expected-value

The solution to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261889/expectation-of-stopping-time-w-r-t-a-brownian-motion) states that $E(\tau)=E(B_{\tau}^2)$. But how do we know this?

Comment: It seems to be explained pretty clearly in the answer.  You show that $B_t^2 - t$ is a martingale and then you apply the optional stopping theorem.  Can you explain which part of that you are asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the hint given above only applies to deterministic $t$, not to random time $\tau$. The problem here is that $$
E[B^2_\tau |\tau = t] \neq t.$$ You should use the fact that $$
B^2_t - t$$ is a continuous $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$-martingale. By optional sampling theorem, we have
$$
E[B^2_{\tau\wedge t} - (\tau\wedge t)] = 0.
$$ Now, let $t\to \infty$ and conclude that
$$
E[B^2_{\tau}]=E[\tau].
$$ (by Lebesgue's dominated convergence and monotone convergence theorem.)

Answer (score 0):

Ohh wait I see, it's because it's a property of standard Brownian motion that $B_t^2=t$ for all $t \ge 0$!!

Since $B(t) \sim N(0, t)$, so $Var(B_t)=t=E(B_t^2)-E(B_t)^2=E(B_t^2)$.

Comment: It's not true that $B_t^2 = t$.  It's true that $E[B_t^2] = t$.  But this property does not automatically carry over when you replace a constant time $t$ by a stopping time.  One has to prove it.