# $\mathbb{E}B_\tau$ where $\tau$ is defined as follows

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $B = (B_t)_t$ be a Standard Brownian motion and $\tau$ is defined as:
$$
\tau = \inf\{t\geq 0: B_t = -1 \text{ or } B_t = 5\}
$$

I want to show that $\mathbb E B_\tau = 0.$

What I have done:

I first try to do this exercise with $\tau$ defined when the hitting was $-1$ or $1$, that is,
$\tau = \{t\geq 0: B_1 = 1 \text{ or } B_t = -1\}$. In this case, $\tau$ can be written as $\min(\tau_1, \tau_{-1})$ where $\tau_i$ are the hitting times with respect to $1$ and $-1$ respectively. Hence, I thought it would be useful to write $B_\tau = B_\tau\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_1 < \tau_{-1}\}} + B_\tau\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_1 > \tau_{-1}\}} = \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_1 <\tau_{-1}\}} - \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_1>\tau_{-1}\}}$. Then, when calculating the expectation:
$$
\mathbb E B_\tau = \mathbb P\{\tau_1 <\tau_{-1}\} -  \mathbb P\{\tau_1 >\tau_{-1}\}
$$

I have some intuition that why this thing is equal to $0$, because this probabilities should (I think) be equal, but I don't see how to prove it easily.

However, in the first situation, there's a $5$  that turns the expectation into:

$$
\mathbb E B_\tau = \mathbb P\{\tau_1 <\tau_{-1}\} -  5\mathbb P\{\tau_1 >\tau_{5}\}
$$
and here I completely get lost. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Maybe use the Doob's optional theorem with the stopping time ${\tau \wedge t}$ and use the fact that the process $\{B\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingale.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261889/36150)

Comment: I've checking: is it that $|B_{t\wedge \tau}|\leq 1, \forall t\geq 0$, then $\tau$ is optional and hence $\mathbb{E}B_\tau = \mathbb{E}B_0 = 0$?

Comment: @saz Oh, it's true! Thank you very much